# Is there a way to open a file that is at least 5 seconds old?

Tags: vb.net, file

I have two processes, one receive data and save in to a file on a specific folder.
The second process check every second if there a new file in that folder, read it and delete it but time to time the second process try to open the file while is being created and get and exception; so I was thinking in to open only files that are at least 5 second old.
Currently I'm using this code.

```
Dim FilePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles(ReportPath, "Report*.rpt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

And read that you can get the file creation time with this code

```
File.GetCreationTime(FilePath))
```

But I'm not sure if is possible to get the file creation time without getting the same exception.

Any ideas how to solve this?
Maybe in a different way.

Comment: why not just handle the exception and try again?

Comment: How do you know the file - which presumably contains data to process - is complete?

Comment: @blaze_125 I'm trying on the next second but since is an automated application for a server I'm writing a log that get a bit dirty with that "false" exceptions. The application works ok; I'm just "splitting hairs".

Comment: @AndrewHenle Are you asking to me?

Comment: You need to synchronize your proccesses with messages

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Btw  I used Linqpad it makes testing these faster..

```
Dim root As String = "C:\linqpad" 

'Take a snapshot of the folder contents 
Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(root)

Dim fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

' This query will produce the full path for all .rpt files 
' under the specified folder including subfolders. 
' It orders the list according to the file name. 
Dim fileQuery = From file In fileList _
                Where file.Extension = ".rpt"  
                Order By file.Length _
                Select file.FullName,file.CreationTime
```

to see the output in linqpad use

```
fileQuery.dump()
```

but this does not translate into anything in Visual studio